# JqueryUI Position plugin: collision applied to a container?

Tags: jquery

Can you recommend a way to use the JqueryUI Position plugin so that the collision logic is applied to a container div rather than the window viewport?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The [jQuery UI Position](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Position) demo uses an `<iframe>` element to achieve roughly the same effect.